# How can I set Input argument that will be used in class declaration?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `A` with 1 method called `public int get(int x, int y)`.

Classes `B`,`C`,`D` have 1 method which are all same and they extends to the abstract class `A`.

In a class `Car`, the `Car` constructor receives String argument `type` that should be used to decide which one of `B`, `C`, `D` have to be used in the class.

Apparently, I am using `if...else` conditional statements based on the `type` to do it.

So the codes look like

```
if(type.equals("B")){
    A = new B();
} else if(type.equals("C")){
    A = new C();
}  //and so on..
```

Is there any elegant way that I can use string argument just as it is to decide which one of 3 classes to use?

Comment: Why are you doing things this way? Is this a requirement of a class assignment? If not, perhaps you should tell us more about the overall problem that you're trying to solve and not the specifics of how you're trying to solve it by code. Perhaps there's a completely different and better way to tackle this.

Comment: No there is no requirement, I am just wondering if there is a way to do that. After creating various classes, I just do not want to see a lot of conditional statements in a single method.

Comment: This design smells wonky, even if you find a more elegant way to do the same thing. I think that you're better off not even pursuing what you're trying to do, and solving the overall design problem instead. If you still need our help then we need more information about what problem you're trying to solve, not how you're trying to solve it. So the question shouldn't be "how can I build a better kludge", but "how can avoid this kludge entirely".

Comment: I solved the problem by passing the class as argument. That was elegant for me :)

Comment: good, that sounds much better and is what Charles Goodwin suggested and is called dependency injection. I ask that you "accept" Charles Goodwin's answer as you are following his advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the interface / abstract class as an argument in the constructor instead of using a String.

```
public Car(A a) { this.a = a; }
```

And then elsewhere:

```
B b = new B();
new Car(b);
```

This is called [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: Dependency injection -- now that's what I'm talking about: an answer that solves the problem, not the question. 1+

Comment: @Hovercraft are you implying I have a habit of doing the latter?  (Truth is I probably do, I'm learning whilst answering half the time.) :b

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Class.forName(String)` to get a `Class` object and then instantiate it using `newInstance()`